# SoapUI/Netbeans crashes on excuting a SOAP request

Tags: netbeans, soapui

This is what happens:

1. Open netbeans
2. Open the SOAP request of the SoapUi project
3. Execute the operation

... then Netbeans fails again and crashes.

Netbeans used to not crash so, I'm unsure what is wrong. Is there a log or anything that could help me track down the issue or, atleast narrow it down?

P.S.

I'm on Windows.

Comment: My notion of Windows triggered me to reboot and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot Windows and it works again.